# How do you connect to a Cosmos Db (primarily updated via SQL API) using Gremlin.Net ? (can you?)

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, gremlin

Im working on a Cosmos DB app that stores both standard documents and graph documents. We are saving both types via the documentdb api and I am able to run graph queries that return Graphson using the DocumentClient.CreateGremlinQuery method. This graphson is to be read by a web app and the graph displayed for user viewing and so on.

My issue is that I cannot define the version of the Graphson format returned when using the Microsoft.Azure.Graphs method. So i looked into Gremlin.net and that has a lot more options in this regard from the documentation.

However I am finding connecting to the Cosmos Document Db using gremlin.net difficult. The server variable which you define like this :

var server = new GremlinServer("https://localhost/",8081 , enableSsl: true, username: $"/dbs/TheDatabase/colls/TheCOllection", password: "C2y6yDjf5/R+ob0N8A7Cgv30VRDJIWEHLM+4QDU5DE2nQ9nDuVTqobD4b8mGGyPMbIZnqyMsEcaGQy67XIw/Jw==");

then results in a uri that has "/gremlin" and it cannot locate the database end point.

Has anyone used Gremlin.net to connect to a Cosmos document database (not a Cosmos db configured as a graph db) that has been setup as a document db not a graph db ? The documents in it are graph/gremlin compatible in their format with _isEdge / label / _sink etc.

Cheers,

Mark (Document db/Gremlin/graph newbie)

Comment: In case anyone out there wants to use both the Gremlin API and the SQL API to access an underlying Cosmos DB the recommended way to do it is to setup a Graph Database in Cosmos first. Then this can be accessed by the gremlin api and also can be accessed by the sql/document api. Louis from MS recommended doing it this way instead of the reverse which was what we had done (create a SQL API doc db and wanting to access it via gremlin as well). Key to also know is that valid edge objects can only contain name / value pairs not nested json etc in line with the Tinkerpop guidelines.